# Best way to use nested recyclerview(or any kind of list) in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm writing a messenger like app. I already have a recyclerview for drawing messages list. But also, i need to draw some attachments inside of each message(like images, sound, files and so). The data strucutre of message is:

```
    "id": 2,
    "text": "Test",
    "sendTime": "21:31 12.10.22",
    "userId": 1,
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "login": "geckon01",
        "email": "geckon01@example.com",
        "role": "host",
        "lastOnline": "2022-10-23T11:03:57.6349417",
        "avatarFileId": 0,
        "avatarBase64": null
    },
    "attachments": [{
        "id": 1,
        "type": "Image",
        "data": null,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "login": "geckon01",
            "email": "geckon01@example.com",
            "role": "host",
            "lastOnline": "2022-10-23T11:03:57.6349417",
            "avatarFileId": 0,
            "avatarBase64": null
        },
        "file": {
            "id": 1,
            "directory": "graphics",
            "fileName": "1c08af89-41f2-4f85-bb5a-3336a37e51bf.jpg",
            "type": "Graphics",
            "fileOwner": {
                "id": 1,
                "login": "geckon01",
                "email": "geckon01@example.com",
                "role": "host",
                "lastOnline": "2022-10-23T11:03:57.6349417",
                "avatarFileId": 0,
                "avatarBase64": null
            }
        },
        "messageId": 2
    }]
}
```

So, i need to draw different view for attachemnt depend on its type. I'm thought to use fragments, but in my opinion it can be slow.
Complite message, should be like this, where item1,3,4 can be image,file,text and so.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what your actual question is regarding the post as currently phrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ConcatAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter). The idea is you create different adapter for each view type. Here's a pseudo code

```
val concatAdapter = ConcatAdapter()

val headerAdapter = HeaderAdapter()
val messagesAdapter = MessagesAdapter()
val attachmentAdapter = AttachmentAdapter()

concatAdapter.add(headerAdapter)
concatAdapter.add(messagesAdapter)
concatAdapter.add(attachmentAdapter)

recyclerView.adapter = concatAdapter
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this. Also, now i see MergeAdapter in android docs. Can I ask what the difference between them?

Comment: I can't seem to find the MergeAdapter you are talking about in the documentation but I read it was renamed to ConcatAdapter. So I guess they are just the same.

Comment: I've read about this adapter and looks like it's not what I need(or, maybe I don't understaand how it works). I mean, i need one adapter inside another. I have a recyclerview with a bunch of message views and I need another one recyclerview inside of message view with a list of attachments view(also, attachments can have different xml). And also, one message can contain attachments with differend types.

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong. 
1.You have this 'Parent' recycler that holds all the messages.
2.Each item of that 'Parent' recyclerview contains the Profile pic of the user,message metadata(text,createBy...etc)
and attachments which is also a recyclerview.
3. The attachment varies depending on the type.

If Im correct you should be creating different adapter for each type of Attachment ex:

`ImageAttachmentAdapter()
FileAttachmentAdapter()`

then attach that on your Attachment RecyclerView which is inside of your `MessageAdapter`

Comment: Yeah, like so. But I'm not sure about speed. Is nesting recycler and adapters is good choice?

Comment: That's should be fine. If there's one I would worry is how I would load the images/attachments.